# Oscillator circle and oscillator plane

Tags: differential-geometry

Studying Differential Geometry I saw two quite similar names: oscillating circle and oscillating plane. What would be the relationship between them?

Comment: Perhaps you mean osculating?

Comment: Yes. The google translate did not help me.

Comment: The osculating circle lies in the osculating plane.

Comment: Would this help me prove that a positive curvature curve is contained in a circle?

Comment: Any bounded set in the plane is contained in a circle; any unbounded set is not.